# The local repository is out of date

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

I'm trying to commit my project to GitHub but this is happening. Can someone please explain to me how to go about it? Iv got the local and remote - why are they not merging/syncing?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJDfM.png]

Comment: Do `git pull` and you should be good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- After you work for your project someone pushed the remote so you are
  not updated.
- You should to `pull` from the remote, `merge` your code to
  local and, Finally you can `push` without error.
- I suggest using the SourceTree or Github Desktop if you are not so much familiar with the git commands, they are much user friendly.